# Tipsy is showing various tooltips at the same position

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a list of vertically-aligned images surrounded with anchor tags. Each anchor tag has a rel='tipsy' attribute and a title attribute with the content of the html that should go in the tipsy tooltip. When I hover over one of the images, its tooltip renders properly, but its position is always on the top image.

Here is the javascript snippet that I have on the page:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[rel=tipsy]').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'w', fallback: "Couldn't Load Info!", html : true, delayIn: 450, delayOut:50, offset:0, opacity:1.0, title:'title', trigger:'hover', live:true }); 
});
```

In the screenshot below, the mouspointer was actually on the lower image, but the tooltip's position is on the first. When I hover over the first image, the tooltip content changes accordingly, but the position is still the same. And the position would also stay the same if I hovered more images in case they were there.

[image: In this screenshot the mouspointer was actually on the lower image, but the tooltip's position is on the first. When I hover over the first image, the tooltip content changes accordingly, but the position is still the same. And the position would also stay the same if I hovered more images in case they were there...]

Comment: It might be related to some css of your html. Can you give us more detail? I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: One way to verify whether the css problem is from your own css is to remove your css files, only leaving tipsy's css files...

Answer (score 0):

try change it to

```
$(function() {
    $('a[rel=tipsy]').each(function(){
        $(this).tipsy({
            fade: true, gravity: 'w', fallback: "Couldn't Load Info!", html : true, delayIn: 450, delayOut:50, offset:0, opacity:1.0, title:'title', trigger:'hover', live:true
        });
    });
});
```